# Initialize an array using openmpi once

Tags: c, openmpi, c89

I am trying to run some tests using OPENmpi processing data in an array by spliting up the work across nodes (the second part is with matricies).  I am running into some problems now because the data array is being initialized every time and I don't know how to prevent this from happening.

How, using ANSI C can I create a variable length array, using OPENmpi once?  I tried making it static and global, but nothing.

```
#define NUM_THREADS 4
#define NUM_DATA 1000

static int *list = NULL;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int numprocs, rank, namelen;
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  int n = NUM_DATA*NUM_DATA;
  printf("hi\n");
  int i;
  if(list == NULL)
  {
     printf("ho\n");
     list = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
      list[i] = rand() % 1000;
    }
  }

  int position;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);
  printf("Process %d on %s out of %d\n", rank,processor_name, numprocs);

  clock_t start = clock();

  position = n / NUM_THREADS * rank;
  search(list,position, n / NUM_THREADS * (rank + 1));

  printf("Time elapsed: %f seconds\n",  ((double)clock() - (double)start) /(double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  free(list);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of giving us just such a lengthy code, could you please be more descriptive of what your goals are, how you try to realize them and what the problems are that you encounter with your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to have the rank 0 process do the initialization while the other processes block.  Then once the initialization is done, have them all start their work.

A basic example trying to call your search function (NB: it's dry-coded):

```
#define NUM_THREADS 4
#define NUM_DATA 1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int *list;
   int numprocs, rank, namelen, i, n;
   int chunksize,offset;
   char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

   n= NUM_DATA * NUM_DATA;

   MPI_Status stat;
   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

   //note you'll need to handle n%NUM_THREADS !=0, but i'm ignoring that for now
   chunksize = n / NUM_THREADS; 

   if (rank == 0) {
      //Think of this as a master process
      //Do your initialization in this process
      list = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

      for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
      {
         list[i] = rand() % 1000;
      }

      // Once you're ready, send each slave process a chunk to work on
      offset = chunksize;
      for(i = 1; i < numprocs; i++) {
         MPI_Send(&list[offset], chunksize, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         offset += chunksize
      }

      search(list, 0, chunksize);

      //If you need some sort of response back from the slaves, do a recv loop here
   } else {

      // If you're not the master, you're a slave process, so wait to receive data

      list = malloc(chunksize*sizeof(int));  
      MPI_Recv(list, chunksize, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);

      // Now you can do work on your portion
      search(list, 0, chunksize);

      //If you need to send something back to the master, do it here.
   }

   MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dusty, that is exactly what I was looking for.  I wasn't even thinking about having the rank 0 be the master and the rest the workers, instead I was blinded looking for something else.

Comment: No problem.  The rank 0 master is a really common concept across MPI, so I have to be careful not to do the opposite and use it as my only tool sometimes. =D